# How to calcute mean of grouped and aggreagted data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

I have data in columns: User, Action and I want to calculate what is the mean number of action per user.
It will be easier to show it on the example:

I have data like this:

```
   Action User 
       A  User1  
       B  User1  
       B  User1  
       C  User1  
       C  User1  
       C  User1  
       A  User2  
       B  User2  
       B  User2  
       C  User2  
       C  User2  
       C  User2  
       A  User3  
       B  User3  
       B  User3  
       C  User3  
       C  User3
```

The result I want to get is:

```
  Action  Mean usage per user
      A             1.000000
      B             2.000000
      C             2.666667
```

I do not have idea how to move from df_agg to df_result

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "A", "id": 1},
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "B", "id": 2},
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "B", "id": 3},
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "C", "id": 4},
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "C", "id": 5},
    {"User": "User1", "Action": "C", "id": 6},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "A", "id": 7},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "B", "id": 8},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "B", "id": 9},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "C", "id": 10},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "C", "id": 11},
    {"User": "User2", "Action": "C", "id": 12},
    {"User": "User3", "Action": "A", "id": 13},
    {"User": "User3", "Action": "B", "id": 14},
    {"User": "User3", "Action": "B", "id": 15},
    {"User": "User3", "Action": "C", "id": 16},
    {"User": "User3", "Action": "C", "id": 17},
])
print(df)

df_agg = df.groupby(["Action", "User"]).agg({"id": ["count"]})
print(df_agg)

df_result = DataFrame([
    {"Action": "A", "Mean usage per user": 1},
    {"Action": "B", "Mean usage per user": 2},
    {"Action": "C", "Mean usage per user": 8 / 3},
])
print(df_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) then [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

```
(df.groupby(['User','Action']).
          size().unstack().mean())
Action
A    1.000000
B    2.000000
C    2.666667
dtype: float64

# to get dataframe as output
(df.groupby(['User','Action']).
          size().unstack().mean().
          reset_index(name='Mean usage per user'))

  Action  Mean usage per user
0      A             1.000000
1      B             2.000000
2      C             2.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
df_final = (df.groupby("Action").User.agg(lambda x: x.size / len(x.unique()))
              .reset_index(name='Mean usage per user'))

Out[14]:
  Action  Mean usage per user
0      A             1.000000
1      B             2.000000
2      C             2.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with `mean` per second level:

```
df=df.groupby(['User','Action']).size().mean(level=1).reset_index(name='Mean usage per user')
print (df)

      Action  Mean usage per user
0      A             1.000000
1      B             2.000000
2      C             2.666667
```